# stbt batch run won't work from C# code

Tags: linux, shell, fedora

I have a Shell script file in Fedora with name **run.sh**. This shell file contains following code:

```
stbt run -1 /home/shan/test/test.py
```

stbt run is one among the command in stb tester which is used commonly for performing soak and stress test.

**test.py** contains some python scripts which will perform some actions as directed by stbt run.

When I execute run.sh directly from terminal it works just fine and yields the desired result. But I want to execute run.sh from C# code. I created and ran a demo script file **run1.sh** from c# code which creates a new folder. The problem is when I try to execute **run.sh** the command stbt wont run. However I changed my **run.sh** file as below:

```
mkdir /home/shan/test/new1
stbt run -1 /home/shan/test/test.py
mkdir /home/shan/test/new2
```

Now in this case both the folders new1 and new2 is created but **stbt batch run** command won't work. The same when executed  from terminal works great.The C# method which triggers the run.sh is below:

```
private String runCron()
{                       
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo ();
    ps.FileName = "/home/shan/test/run.sh";
    ps.UseShellExecute = false;
    ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process process = Process.Start (ps);
    process.WaitForExit ();

    return "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

friend chage your process directory path

ps.FileName = "/home/kc/test/run1.sh";

to

ps.FileName = "/home/shan/test/run1.sh";

Comment: Oh sorry mate, perils of copy paste. I modified the question and this is how I'm executing in real. Issue still on